# Spring sseEmitter, events aren't sent right after method send was called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, server-sent-events

I am trying to make server-sent events with Spring 4 (tomcat 7, servlet-api 3.0.1).

The problem is my `Events` aren't sent right after method send was called. They all come simultaneously (with same timestamp) to client only after timeout of `SseEmitter`, with `EventSource`'s error event. And then client is trying to reconnect. Any idea what's happening?

I have created a simple service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "subscribe", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SseEmitter subscribe () throws IOException {
    final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().data("Thread writing: " + Thread.currentThread()).name("ping"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    } , 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    return emitter;
}
```

with client code:

```
sse = new EventSource(urlBuilder(base, url));
sse.addEventListener('ping', function (event) {
    dfd.notify(event);
});

sse.addEventListener('message', function(event){
    dfd.notify(event);
});

sse.addEventListener('close', function(event){
    dfd.notify(event);
});

sse.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log(error);
};

sse.onmessage = function (event){
    dfd.notify(event);
};
```

App initalizer code

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ctx.refresh();

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        dynamic.setAsyncSupported(true);
        dynamic.addMapping("/api/*");
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dynamic.setMultipartConfig(ctx.getBean(MultipartConfigElement.class));

        javax.servlet.FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = servletContext
                .addFilter("StatelessAuthenticationFilter",
                        ctx.getBean("statelessAuthenticationFilter", StatelessAuthenticationFilter.class));
        filter.setAsyncSupported(true);
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/api/*");

        filter = servletContext.addFilter("HibernateSessionRequestFilter",
                ctx.getBean("hibernateSessionRequestFilter", HibernateSessionRequestFilter.class));
        filter.setAsyncSupported(true);
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/api/user/*");
    }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.esoft.workflow")
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource({"classpath:mail.properties", "classpath:fatclient.properties"})
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

Image of my client log:
[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem. However, after reading https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14578
I tried it with a `Thread` and `Thread.start()` , and it seems the problem disappeared, but I don´t know really why. Anyway, I think it is strange if it worked in combination with RxJava, although it is certainly a better approach.

Comment: I create a JIRA improvement for this (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15299) since I have the same issue. Let's see how it goes...

Comment: In my case it turned out that the IIS sitting in between the browser and Tomcat was the problem (follow my previous comment on the reported bug and you will find the full explanation).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this myself when testing SSEEmitters.  From everything I've read online, SSEEmitters are meant to be used in conjunction with some implementation of [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/), such as [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).  It's a bit complex, but it definitely works.  The idea is that you create the emitter, and an Observable, and subscribe the latter to a Publisher.  The Publisher executes its behavior in a separate thread, notifying the Observable when output is ready, and the observable triggers the emitter.send.  Here is an example snippet that should do what you want:

```
@RequestMapping("/whatever")
public SseEmitter index(    
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    Publisher<String> responsePublisher = someResponseGenerator.getPublisher();
    Observable<String> responseObservable = RxReactiveStreams.toObservable(responsePublisher);

    responseObservable.subscribe(
        str -> {
            try {
                emitter.send(str);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                emitter.completeWithError(ex);
            }
        },
        error -> {
            emitter.completeWithError(error);
        },
        emitter::complete
        );

        return emitter;
};
```

Here is a the corresponding Publisher:

```
public class SomeResponseGenerator {    
    public Publisher<String> getPublisher() {
        Publisher<String> pub = new Publisher<String>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(Subscriber subscriber) {
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        subscriber.onNext("Thread writing: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }
                }, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
        };

        return pub;
    }
}
```

There are a few examples of this model online [here](http://www.grahamlea.com/2014/07/rxjava-threading-examples/) and [here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/07/server-sent-events-with-rxjava-and.html), and you can find more by Googling 'RxJava SseEmitter'.  It takes some time to grok the Reactive Streams/RxJava/SseEmitter interactions, but once you do it is pretty elegant.  Hope this sets you on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer is correct, if you want to manage it yourself you can call:

```
emitter.complete()
```